# Last 7 days in a select Tag without form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

In my Angular application i am supposed to list past 7 days in a select tag with in a form, As a part of it, i managed to list them in a simple way, Code as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <form name="datelist">
        <select  name="prevdays" style="width:200px">
            <option selected value="#">pick one</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
   window.onload = function() {
            var noOfDays = 10;
            var msPerDay = 86400000;
            var months = new Array("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12");
            var d = document;
            console.log(document);
            var f = d.datelist;
            var s = f.prevdays;
            // change i to 1 if you want to start with yesterday.
            for (i = 0; i < noOfDays; i++) {
                var D = new Date();
                with(D) {
                    setTime(valueOf() - (i * msPerDay));
                }
/*                var txt = months[D.getMonth()] + ' ' + D.getDate() + ', ' + D.getFullYear();
*/
          var txt = D.getFullYear() + '-'+months[D.getMonth()] +'-'+ D.getDate() ;

                var val = D.getFullYear() + '' + (D.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? '0' + (D.getMonth() + 1) : D.getMonth() + 1) + '' + (D.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + D.getDate() : D.getDate());
                s.options[s.options.length] = new Option(txt, val);
            }

        }
```

So here 2 problems :

1) That HTML i should place them in a form tag ,But as i understood nested `form` tags are not allowed so far in HTML (????), How can overcome this issue ??

2) This above solution works only without angular,if i place this same code in my real angular application it does not work (prevdays),it just shows only one `option` ie., `<option selected value="#">pick one</option>`

in DOM tree.

FYI: console error as

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prevdays' of undefined.

Any kind of help much appreciated, Thanks for your time.

Comment: You will probably be better off using something like moment.js and the subtract functionality in a loop: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/

Answer (score 0):

```
var f = d.datelist;
```

In that line, you are trying to access the form by name, but you can't do it like that. In HTML5, accessing elements by name is deprecated, so you should use ID's instead.

```
var f = d.getElementById("datelist");
var s = f.children[0];     //You could also give it an ID if you prefer
```

This is why it's undefined.

You can also use a select element outside of forms, so you don't have to worry about nesting forms.